# I'm having an issue in my androidManifest.xml file with setting parent activity

Tags: java, android

So what I need is to make my mainActivity the parent and mainActivity2 child to the parent. I did that, but when I run my app with how it is now, all it shows is a blank screen and a back arrow for navigation. [image]
When I switch those two and make mainActivity2 the parent and run the app, my mainActivity page loads up but with a back arrow. [image] Both those things should not happen. There should not be a back arrow on the main screen and mainActivity2 should not have the mainActivity page loaded in. I'm going to drop in some pics and files. Any help would be appreciated.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidjavaproject1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidJavaProject1">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidjavaproject1.MainActivity2"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.androidjavaproject1.MainActivity">
            

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidjavaproject1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE =  "com.example.androidjavaproject1.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    // create second activity for the app on start button click
    public void startClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

Comment: I also tried using the meta-data in the xml file but it didn't help any. Plus my version is newer so I shouldn't need it

Comment: Why there is no MainActivity in your manifest file

Comment: @BernhardJosephus could you be more specific? I mean, I have my MainActivity set as the parent activity name.

Comment: Okay, so usually, if you have an activity, it will be registered on the manifest. So, in your case, you have MainActivity and MainActivity2, but only MainActivity2 registered on the manifest (registered by `<activity>` tag).

Comment: @BernhardJosephus are you saying that I cant have both those activities named under the same <activity> tag? I must create another tag?

Comment: That's not what I mean actually. Every activity should be registered on the manifest file. What you are doing right now is okay. You are telling the MainActivity2 parent is MainActivity. But, I'm afraid that Android can't find your MainActivity, because it hasn't been registered yet.

Comment: Btw, if I understand correctly, you want your app, at first launch open MainActivity, and when a button pressed, go to the MainActivity2 (which has the back button to go back to the MainActivity)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But what you said earlier was brilliant and I got it working. I needed an extra <activity> tag to register the mainactivity name and now it is working as needed

Comment: Nice, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.androidjavaproject1">
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidJavaProject1">
    
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity2">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
          <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    
        </application>
    </manifest>
```